# Showing popups from StandoutWindow

Tags: android, android-standout

I am using standout library for showing floating windows. It's working great except that it can not be used to call AlertDialogs (or Dialogs of any kind). I just need a DateTime Picker and a simple alert. I tried using AlertDialog, but since the window is not an Activity Context.

I tried using Standout window again for the same purpose. I put a button on the current window and tried showing the second window from the first one, but the window does not appear at all. I am using a service context to initialize the window.

The logcat is not showing any kind of error at all. I am not sure if its possible to call one window from another.

Is there any way to do the same?